# Spring boot load all properties files in directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Before:

I had a big properties file in which I had all my properties, which I used to load like this:

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:C:\\Users\\xxx\\yyy\\conf\\context.properties", name = "cntx.props")
```

and then get my properties like this:

```
AbstractEnvironment ae = (AbstractEnvironment)env;
PropertySource source = ae.getPropertySources().get("cntx.props");
Properties properties = (Properties)source.getSource();

for(Object key : properties.keySet()) {
    ...
}
```

and i would call `env.getProperty("someKey")` whenever I need to access a value.

After:

I had to make it as such instead of loading one big properties files, I would need to make multiple smaller properties files and load them from the same folder.

For that I configured a property configuration bean manually in my Config class:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() throws NamingException {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\yyy\\conf");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".properties");
        }
    });

    FileSystemResource[] resources = new FileSystemResource[files.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
        resources[i] = new FileSystemResource(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }

    properties.setLocations(resources);
    properties.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return properties;
}
```

So far so good. I then defined a global map variable to fill it with my key value pairs.

```
@Bean
public void getPropsFromFile() {
    propertiesMap = new HashMap();
    for(Iterator it = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource propertySource = (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource) it.next();
        if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
            propertiesMap.putAll(((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getSource());
        }
    }

    // check what's in the map
    for (String key : propertiesMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + propertiesMap.get(key).toString());
    }
}
```

But when I check what's in the map, it's a bunch of values like this:

> java.vm.vendor : Oracle Corporation PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE : AMD64
> PSModulePath : C:\Program
> Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
> user.variant :  MAVEN_HOME : C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.5
> user.timezone : Europe/Paris

I was expecting it too be filled with the properties I defined in my files.

What am I missing? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at creating an EnvironmentPostProcessor to provide for loading multiple files.
You'll have control of the order and decide which properties will take precedence.